# Convert Date into a format to extract the Year in MySQL Select Statement

Tags: mysql

I have a date in a table formatted like this:

```
31-May-90
```

I need to get the year - 1990 in my MySQL statement.  I tried:

```
year(tblPhotoManage.Date) AS cpYear
```

Obviously this won't work.  How can I get the year from this date format?

Comment: review https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: So its not a date, its a string that looks like a date, so you either have to convert it into a DATE and then use date function on it, or use string function on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert the string that looks a bit like a date into a MySQL DATE datatype, then using the `YEAR()` function that only works on DATE/DATETIME datatypes to get the year

```
SELECT YEAR(STR_TO_DATE('31-May-90','%d-%M-%y'));
```

Comment: I had just found that.  It returns 1990.  Thanks!